# Is there any extra step we need to do when changing web hosting company with HTTPS site?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, https, shared-hosting, site-move

I have bought domains from A company.

My all sites were in shared hosting account on Company B.

I have moved my all sites to  shared hosting account on Company C from B. I know the all the steps.

Now I wanted to move my sites from company C to company B. But now my sites have HTTPS thanks to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) WordPress plugin.

Is there any extra step should I do when moving my sites from new hosting account because  of now I having HTTPS?

Comment: Redirect all non-ssl traffic to SSL.

Comment: @SimonHayter I have already done it on current hosting. Do I need to do some more after migrating too?

Comment: Have you served an HSTS header, and are you on the preload list?

Comment: @jrtapsell HSTS header?? Preload list means?

Comment: [HSTS](https://www.troyhunt.com/understanding-http-strict-transport/) removes the option of serving over HTTP, so you would need to have SSL set up to access any config pages, [preloading](https://hstspreload.org/) acheives the same, but without needing an inital visit

Comment: The question not pointed on true fog.  is it about your site, your domain or your hosting? you have ssl. if you changed IP (because of changing your hosting) so you need to renew (reissue) your SSL certificates.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any extra step should I do when moving my sites from new hosting account because of now I having HTTPS?

add

```
    Options -Indexes
```

to the .htaccess to prevent directory surfing.
add these to prevent common attacks in .htaccess:
  deny all access to hidden files/directories.:

```
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RedirectMatch 404 /\..*$
```

These are to stop mysql injections and other exploits, but I had originally just two rewrite conditions. However, I'm updating this list to include other attacks 
(update)

```
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(%2d|\-)[^=]+$ [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|\.\.) [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>).* [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\./|\../|\.../)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

we can add other bad requests and deny user agents ect.
looks like this hosting guy goes into detail about it.
https://secure.rivalhost.com/knowledgebase/1037/htaccess-against-MySQL-injections-and-other-hacks.html

Comment: it seems like the hackers on-line on this forum don't want this out...lol

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're not really answering the question with regards to the HTTP to HTTPS migration - there's nothing specific to HTTPS here. Your code block is without any explanation of what it actually does (how does it "prevent common attacks"?). One thing you should never do is use code in `.htaccess` that you don't understand... it doesn't _look like_ those directives actually do anything? The two _conditions_ that check against the `QUERY_STRING` are mutually exclusive so the rule will never be successful. That `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) directive is certainly misplaced.

Comment: I'll clarify it for you..